# Simple Form - setting an association collection to a default id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i am unsure how to go about resolving the below. Any help will be much appreciated

- i have a user whoes profile states they comes from a country with an country_category_id: 8
- when the user is completing an application form i would like to set the country select option by default to the country the user comes from (country_category_id: 8) as stated in the user's profile
- in the _form.html.erb i have managed to this with firstname by adding "value: current_user.firstname"

> question: could one advise how this would be done for s simpleform
>   association select option - setting the country select option to a default id based on the user country id

many thanks

schema

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.integer  "number"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "language"
    t.integer  "category_country_id"
  end


  create_table "forms", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.integer  "number"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "category_country_id"
  end

  create_table "category_countries", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

model

```
User belongs_to category_country
Form belongs_to category_country

CategoryCountry has_many users
CategoryCountry has_many forms
```

views: forms / _form.html.erb

```
<%= f.input_field :firstname, value: current_user.firstname %>
<%= f.association :category_country, collection: CategoryCountry.all, prompt: "select a category", label: "current country (you currently live in)", :value => current_user.category_country.name %>
```

forms_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @form = Form.new
  end

  def create
    @form = Form.new(form_params)
    @form.user_id = current_user.id
    if @form.save
      redirect_to application_submitted_path
    else
      redirect_to user_advert_path(advert.user, advert)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked with rails in a while but I'm trying to help.

Have you tried inserting `:selected => current_user.category_country_id`

```
<%= f.association :category_country, collection: CategoryCountry.all, prompt: "select a category", label: "current country (you currently live in)", :value => current_user.category_country.name, :selected => current_user.category_country_id   %>
```

Comment: you are awesome!! thank you soo much
`<%= f.association :category_country, collection: CategoryCountry.all, prompt: "select a category", label: "current country (you currently live in)", :value => current_user.category_country.name, :selected => current_user.category_country_id  %>`